# Trying to create a 3 dimensional vector in c++

Tags: c++

So, im trying to create a 3 dimensional 5x3x2 vector, using the vector lib and saving the number 4 in every node.

Thats what im trying:

```
vector<vector<vector<int> > > vec (5,vector <int>(3,vector <int>(2,4)));
```

for a bi dimensional 5x8 saving the int 6 in every node, this works:

```
vector<vector<int> > vec (5,vector <int>(8,6));
```

Comment: A 3D vector is something like <-1, -2, 4>. You're talking about a 3D array (simulated using a vector of vectors of vectors). A vector is a 1D array, no matter how large a number of dimensions it has.

Comment: Please don't do this. Use `boost::multi_array`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Using Boost may not be appropriate for all people, due to licensing or build footprint constraints.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You almost got it right -- the second nested `vector` should be `vector<vector<int> >`, not just a `vector<int>`:

```
vector<vector<vector<int> > > vec (5,vector<vector<int> >(3,vector <int>(2,4)));
```

Answer (score 18):

Also you can declare of this forms:

```
// first form
typedef vector<int> v1d;
typedef vector<v1d> v2d;
typedef vector<v2d> v3d;
v3d v(5, v2d(3, v1d(2, 4)));

// second form
vector<vector<vector<int> > > v = vector<vector<vector<int> > >( 5, vector<vector<int> >(3, vector<int>(2, 4)))
```